# What happens if a function that is not defined as a view, doesn't change the data of the contract?

Tags: brownie, view, function

**example:**

```
function addAllowedTokens(address _token) public onlyOwner {
        if (!tokenIsAllowed(_token)) {
            allowedTokens[_token] = true;
        }
    }
```

In this code, the `allowedTokens` mapping won't always be modified? I have a test that calls this functions and doesn't modify the mapping, and it passes but a lot of weird console stuff gets printed.

MORAL OF QUESTION IS: WHAT HAPPENS WHEN A NON-VIEW FUNCTION IS CALLED AND DOESN'T MODIFY THE SMART CONTRACT?

My intuition is that this should be fine and just run. But seems like something different may be happening.

Answer (score 0):

It wastes gas because people will call it on-chain